# What is the latency on writing to Azure OMS log analytics?

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

We are using SeriLog to write logs to OMS however there is approx 50 minutes delay from when we write a log to when it appears in search results on the Azure portal.

I have searched google but I cannot find any references to what kind of latency we can expect. Does anyone have more information?

Comment: its definitely not 50 minutes.

Comment: Same thing with our setup a few months ago. Kubernetes pods running in Azure is about a ~40 minute delay. Fast forward to today and it's delayed up to 2-3 days. fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [documentations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/data-ingestion-time#typical-latency) typical latency to ingest log data is between 2 and 5 minutes.